# Intuitionistic validity of implication

Tags: logic

Basically I am wondering whether $(((((P\implies Q)\implies P)\implies P)\implies Q)\implies Q)$ is valid in intuitionistic logic. A proof of the relevant conclusion (valid or invalid) would be nice, but is not essential. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid in intuitionistic logic.

In order to prove it, it is useful to notice that if $B$ is valid, then $A \to B$ is valid as well.